# difference in difference regression with panel data in pandas +python

Tags: python, pandas, regression, panel-data

I have a big panel data datafarme, ratios of different companies in different years, my data frame imagine like this :(MR and RA are control variables , LCR dependent variable in regression) I want to observe the effect of WFR on LCR

```
`data = {'NAME': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
    'YEAR': [2017, 2009, 2011, 2017, 2018, 2010, 2018, 2014, 2015, 2016],
    'WFR': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
   'LCR':[4,3,6,9,8,2,3,5,6,7],
   'MR':[8,6,5,7,3,2,1,5,6,7],
   'RA':[12,23,12,13,15,18,13,19,12,11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)`
```

I have created treatment and control group according to WFR. if WFR=1 it is a treatment otherwise it is control group.
the problem for me is that I have different LCR in different years and different companies(panel data)
how can I run a difference in difference regression for that? any idea? thanks .

Comment: @Stefan do you have any idea?

Comment: @etna any idea?

Comment: Difference-in-differences works for situations where you are comparing the differences between the treatment and control groups before and after an intervention/policy change. I don't see an intervention here. With your available data, you will be able to compare the LCR between groups by including the WFR variable as a regressor. You can also compare the growth rate in LCR by creating a growth rate variable and including it.